# GPU Does not Exceed 40 FPS

Tags: graphics-card, java, gpu

In the past whenever I used to play games such as Minecraft, I would frequently exceed 40 FPS. On top of this, a game that I am writing in Java with a group of friends which in the past could achieve 60 FPS now does exceed 40. This is a problem because 40 FPS is not enough for the game to run smoothly.

What could possibly be the problem? I have tried reinstalling Java and have also tried reinstalling my graphics card driver (keep in mind that by reinstall, I mean I ran the install utility on my computer; I did not actually do an uninstall). Here are the stats for my graphics card.

[image: Graphics Card Stats]

Comment: I am pretty sure your display drivers are not current but based in the hardware not shocked your limited to 40 FPS

Comment: You appear to be running driver version 10.18.10.3262. At the time of writing, the latest version is 15.33.22.64.3621. Your driver is almost a year out of date. As DavidB points out, though, your GPU is pretty low-end and will likely have a hard time reaching reasonable framerates on modern games.

Comment: I agree, try changing some video settings in the game, no particles, no clouds, no smooth lighting, reduce render distance and such. Yes, it might become slightly ugly, but we're talking square sun anyway. ;-)

Comment: I had the newer version of my driver installed at the time that this started happening. I was able to reach 60FPS on this computer before so why not know?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - Actually.  The actual driver version is `10.18.10.3621` not `15.33.22.64.3621` which indicates its simply not current.

Comment: @DavidB - Load up an entirely blank Minecraft world.  All I know is your lucky that you are getting 40FPS with that GPU.  Its not bad, but there are tons of other products, that would allow 60FPS on the highest settings.  What version of Java do you have installed exactly?  **I am hesitant to provide an answer to you since you have a habit of not accepting answers.**

Comment: @DavidB: What was your test setting and setup? Identical world, identical resolution, identical settings, **identical version of minecraft**, identical version of Java, identical background software?

Comment: @Ramhound I use Java 8 Update 5 x64. I went through and accepted all answers. `:)`

Comment: @DavidB Are you using the same version of minecraft for both tests? The latest versions of minecraft have been getting more graphically intense.

Comment: @DarthAndroid It does not matter what version of Minecraft I am running. The problem happens with any version of the game.

Comment: How long ago were you getting more then 40fps because that's really decent considering the performance charistics of Minecraft

Comment: @Ramhound I was get over 40 FPS until the other night when I acidentally added code to the game that I am making with friends that continued creating threads over and over that ran infinite loops. After that happened, I never exceeded 40 again. If the game that I was making didn't require more than 40 I would not care.

Comment: The two events are not connected.  its not possible software your writing would be the reason your FPS is limited to 40 FPS.FPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons that I do not fully understand, my graphics card settings were altered. I do not know what the cause of this was, but I have changed the settings back to their defaults, and I am once again able to achieve 60 FPS on both Minecraft and my game.

Comment: Care to share which setting was altered?